# commutator relation should be obvious

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading Stefan Teufel's [Adiabatic Perturbation Theory in Quantum Dynamics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b13355), in which, on page 37 he claims that the following relation is obvious.

Firstly, some context: we have a time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$, with a single eigenvalue $E(t)$. We define
$$ F(t)=-(R(E(t),t) \dot{P}(t) P(t) +  P(t) \dot{P}(t) R(E(t),t) ), $$

$R$ is the resolvent: so $R(E(t),t)=(H(t)-E(t))^{-1}$, and $P$ is the spectral projection onto the eigenspace. They claim that

$$ [H(t),F(t)] =[\dot{P}(t) ,P(t)].$$

They say that this is an obvious equality, but I've been struggling with showing this.

I substituted the definition of $F$, and tried to use that $H$ and $P$ commute, and so does $H$ and $R$, but I keep getting stuck.

Comment: Is $R(E(t),t)$ simply $R(t)$?

Comment: @Marco that was a typo. Fixed it, thanks!